# python opencv + jupyter で mp4 動画をリアルタイムに再生したい

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

jupyter notebook 上でリアルタイムにopencvを使ってmp4ファイルを再生したいのですが、方法はありますでしょうか。
.pyファイルにしてcv2.imshow()で表示させるとリアルタイムになりますが、jupyter上ではとても遅くなってしまいます。
python3を使っています。

現在のコード：

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython import display
%matplotlib inline

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    try:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        plt.imshow(frame)

        display.clear_output(wait=True)
        display.display(plt.gcf())

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        cap.release()
```

Comment: おそらく不可能です。道具には適材適所がありますから、別の手段を考えるか、本当に実現したいことを見直してください。

Comment: @yohjp さん ありがとうございます！サーバーにssh接続をしながら作業しており、ポートフォーワーディングでjupyterは手元のマシーンで開けてるのでそこで動画に処理を施しながら再生ができると作業がしやすかったのですが、別な手段を考えてみます